# Is it possible to ignore disabled functions in php.ini for a particular file only?

Tags: php, security, server, vps

I have a Linux VPS that hosts my website. It's the only website that's hosted on the VPS. I have disabled all php functions that allow the execution of shell commands for security reasons, in particular, I have disabled them to prevent PHP shells that attackers use for hacking systems from working properly.

Recently, I have been thinking to use lossless JPEG compression on my server to optimize the photos that my users upload. I did a thorough research on stackoverflow and realized that I need to install some programs on my server. To use them for compression, these programs should be run via shell access but then that's something I can't allow.

So, my question is this: can I force php to ignore the functions that I have disabled in php.ini for only one particular file (or in worst case scenario for a particular directory) on the server? If not, are there any workarounds that solve my issue?

Thanks

Comment: You will probably have to have another virtual host with php through cgi, that way it will be able to have separate ini file. Or, maybe it would be easier to have some other module, say python, to exec php as shell command with custom ini.

Comment: if its *your* vps, how does disabling them help? are you allowing random people to run code on your server?

Comment: @SergeSeredenko  I will be thankful if you explain in detail what you mean by "have some other module exec php as shell command with custom.ini". And I didn't understand your first idea either. Are you talking about adding a file as a virtual host in Apache? I didn't get it. How?

Comment: @smith  I'm just being ultra cautious that no one hacks into my server because I don't want my users' data stolen.

Comment: if they cant run code, this protects nothing. if they hacked in anyway they can just change the setting. you seem to just be making your own life hard, for no actual benefit.

Comment: I mean that you could add a virtual host, say on a subdomain or other port of your site, and use it for uploading photos. There you could enable `mod_wsgi` and use a simple python script, which would pass all the input into your php script via `subprocess.call`. You could even handle the original request on your main host, save pictures wherever you want, but then call `file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/resize?path=...")`, which would be handled by your virtualhost with python. That way python script would consist of 5-10 lines necessary to call php script.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Thanks. That makes sense. Please expand your comment with a bit of details about mod_wsgi and subprocess.call and write it as an answer to the question that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is *No*.

> [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)
>
> .....
>
> This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this in httpd.conf.

Alternatively you can use one of the following solutions :

- https://github.com/kraken-io/kraken-php
- https://github.com/keycdn/php-optimus-api
- Use Imagick library : [Imagick::setImageCompressionQuality](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php) with a quality near to 100, it is considered [almost lossless](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=31075#p141107)

*OR*

- define some cron jobs that will do that for you every regular X time, this means that the image won't be comprised immediately.